# Puppet - Install PHP with LibXML module, with the XSLT extension enabled (--with-xsl)

Tags: puppet

I need to ensure puppet installs Php with LibXML with the '--with-xsl' flag.

I have the following class for all things php:

```
class php {
   package { "php5-cli": ensure => present }
   package { "php5-dev": ensure => present }
   package { "php5-mysql": ensure => present }
   package { "php-pear": ensure => present }
   package { "php5-common": ensure => present}
   package { "php5-fpm": ensure => present}
   package { "php5-cgi": ensure => present}
   package { "php-apc": ensure => present}

   exec { "pear upgrade":
     command => "/usr/bin/pear upgrade",
     require => Package["php-pear"],
   }
}
```

Not sure how to use flags here.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want to install with `--with-xsl` flag for all of them :

```
all_php_packages = ["php5-cli","php5-dev","php5-mysql","php-pear",
                    "php5-common","php5-fpm","php5-cgi","php-apc"]

package{ $all_php_packages :
   ensure => present,
   install_options => ["--with-xsl","--some-other-option",],
}
```